# Get Items from Enum as String

Tags: java

I have this Enum Structure:

```
public enum PurchaseOrderStatus {
    IN_REVIEW("in_review"),
    CANCELED("canceled"),
    DECLINED("declined"),
    WAITING_REVIEW("waiting_review"),
    IN_TRANSIT("in_transit"),
    COMPLETED("completed");

    private String text;

    PurchaseOrderStatus(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public static Optional<PurchaseOrderStatus> fromText(String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(bl -> bl.text.equalsIgnoreCase(text))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

How I can get item as String? When I try `PurchaseOrderStatus.IN_REVIEW.getText()` I get error `Attribute value must be constant`.

Comment: Works just fine? https://repl.it/repls/LoyalNewAttributes

Comment: Your code works, but you should non the less write `private final String text`, especially in a enum.

Answer (score 1):

`PurchaseOrderStatus.IN_REVIEW.getText()` is it.

That error is not related to 'how to get items from enum as string'. it is related to the fact that you can only use constants in annotation options.

You must be trying to do this in your code:

`@Foobar(PurchaseOrderStatus.IN_REVIEW.getText())` - you can't do that.

If it's your own annotation, note that annotation 'fields' can be enum-typed. So where you currently have:

```
public @interface Foobar {
    String value() default "hello";
}
```

make that:

```
public @interface Foobar {
    PurchaseOrderStatus value() default PurchaseOrderStatus.IN_REVIEW;
}
```

If you can't change the definition of the annotation, well, this won't work, and there really isn't any workaround, you're going to have to 'hardcode' the string someplace.

Note that the entire design of your enum is a bit wonky; you could have just as well written:

```
public enum PurchaseOrderStatus {
    IN_REVIEW, CANCELED, DECLINED, WAITING_REVIEW, IN_TRANSIT, COMPLETED;

    public String getText() {
        return name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use it this way: `@Spec(path = "status", spec = In.class, constVal = PurchaseOrderStatus.IN_REVIEW.getText())`

Comment: yup. My answer fully applies - you can't do that. Period. Change 'String constVal();' in your Spec.java file to 'PurchaseOrderStatus constVal();'.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: The answer is pretty long, I don't think I can do much with 'elaborate even more'.

Comment: I use @Spec from this project: https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver I can't do any change. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Okay. Well, then you can't change it, and there is no workaround. You have to 'hardcode' the name.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work fine; however, I would recommend this change (since it guaranteed that `text` never changes).

Make

```
private String text;
```

into

```
private final String text;
```

Comment: The error is real, just, not related to what OP thinks it is related to. See my answer. Your answer is of the form 'I do not know how to answer your question / I want to close it for lack of reprodicibility or details, but, I want to make unrelated remarks about your code'. I wish SO had a facility to write those up that's better than comments, but, alas.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It wasn't clear that they were attempting to use the value in an annotation context.  Thanks for the update.